# How to delete deployments of a greater than date from awk list

Tags: awk, date

I need to delete deployments that are older than 14 days on clusters.  if I run:

```
oc get deploy --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | grep wml-os-rt-hybrid | awk '{ print $1 "\t\t" $6;}'
```

It gives me a list of those deployments and the age of them:

```
wml-os-rt-hybrid0.1-gz3vczfc        15d
wml-os-rt-hybrid0.1-fj167pbt        8d
wml-os-rt-hybrid0.1-bdzkqi7z        7d
wml-os-rt-hybrid0.1-g4hclw4v        7d
wml-os-rt-hybrid0.1-j6x9tzt6        7d
wml-os-rt-hybrid0.1-qplkkilw        4d
wml-os-rt-hybrid0.1-sadgz9cz        6h
```

I am brand new to this and can not figure out what I need to add so that it would also delete anything older then 14d, in this case it would just be the one line but in other clusters it would be hundreds.

Comment: (d)ays and (h)ours would be the only values.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
oc get deploy --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp |
awk '/wml-os-rt-hybrid/ && !(($6 ~ /d$/) && (($6+0) > 14)){print $1 "\t\t" $6}'
```

Assuming that the thing printed first is your "deployment" and that to delete a "deployment" you can use `oc delete deployment <deployment>` as mentioned in your comment below and what you want to delete are the "deployment"s that DON'T meet the above criteria, then something like this should do it:

```
oc get deploy --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp |
awk '!( /wml-os-rt-hybrid/ && !(($6 ~ /d$/) && (($6+0) > 14)) ){print $1}' |
xargs -n 1 oc delete deployment
```

You can do the boolean algebra to get rid of the double negatives in that condition if you like.

Comment: actually, it looks like that only deletes the results from the printed out result.  I am looking for a way to actually delete the deployment.  Manually I can delete them via oc delete deployment <deployment>

Comment: Because it didnt accomplish what my question asked as stated by a previous comment.

Comment: @mrbarker if you put updates in comments they'll likely get missed. ALL information belongs in the question text.

Answer (score 1):

```
delfile=delete_file_names
... | awk -v delfile="$delfile" 'BEGIN { printf "","" >delfile }; '\
'{ value=$6; sub(".$","",value); '\
'if($6 ~ "h$") value=int(value/24); else value=int(value); }; '\
'value<15 { print $1 "\t\t" $6;}; '\
'value>14 { print $1 >delfile; }'

wml-os-rt-hybrid0.1-fj167pbt            8d
wml-os-rt-hybrid0.1-bdzkqi7z            7d
wml-os-rt-hybrid0.1-g4hclw4v            7d
wml-os-rt-hybrid0.1-j6x9tzt6            7d
wml-os-rt-hybrid0.1-qplkkilw            4d
wml-os-rt-hybrid0.1-sadgz9cz            6h

if [ -s "$delfile" ]; then
    IFS=$'\n' rm -- $(< "$delfile")
fi
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will try test this shortly.  I appreciate it.

Comment: So that returns a list of any deployments that match the filter, but Im looking for a way to have anything that matches that criteria be deleted as well.  Currently I have to run another command which if using my original post would be: oc delete deployment wml-os-rt-hybrid0.1-gz3vczfc

Comment: @mrbarker I extended my answer.